# Can only one rotation make One 3d coordinate system matches to another.

Tags: coordinate-systems, rotations, quaternions

It seems to be idiot, I Wonder "The one rotation can make two random-different 3d coordinate system match."
I searched and learned about Quaternion, and i realized one quaternion (length is 1) can contain one rotation info. but i can't understand their multiplication also can be interpreted as ONE ROTATION.
If above is right, All multiplication between quaternion of rotation means a simple rotation. but not, All I have learned becomes complex to me.

I know it is right and possible intuitively, I want proof (as easy as possible)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am guessing that your question would not include, for instance, rotations about parallel axes? For instance, two rotations of $\pi$ radians around parallel axes can equal a translation. Picture a leaf being flipped over and over by a breeze, and thus progressing end over end down the street

Comment: To echo Paul Tanenbaum: does your notion of "rotation" leave the origin unmoved? Or can you 'rotate' around an arbitrary line? If it's the first, then the answer is 'yes' --- every product of rotations is in fact a rotation (or perhaps the identity map, which is a rotation by angle zero).

Comment: Taking into account the user is talking about quaternions, the context is assuredly special orthogonal transformations of a vector space.  Or at least, that's the context that makes the most sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A coodrdinate system of a normed vector space is established by a choice of ordered basis. By "rotation [...] matches one to another" I take it to mean that the rotation would have to map one ordered basis onto the other ordered basis.

With this understanding, the explanation goes this way.

Firstly, "rotation" means that angles, lengths and orientation will be preserved after the transformation.  This means you can't map a basis element onto one of a different length, the angles between the basis vectors have to match before and after, and the orientation of the two bases have to be the same.

But if the two chosen bases match in all these respects, then yes, there is one, and only one, rotation to transform one to the other.